# How to install poppler on Debian

Tags: linux, pdf, poppler

I already have installed a previous version (version 22) of poppler but when updating to the newest version (version 23) I get a lot of dependency errors?

Which packages are missing?

Distro: Debian Bullseye 11

```
# apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev
# cd /var/bin && wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-23.09.0.tar.xz && tar -xvf poppler-23.09.0.tar.xz
# cd poppler-23.09.0 && mkdir build && cd build
# cmake ..
```

error

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:95 (message):

   No test data found in $testdatadir.
   You will not be able to run 'make test' successfully.

   The test data is not included in the source packages
   and is also not part of the main git repository. Instead,
   you can checkout the test data from its own git
   repository with:

     git clone git://git.freedesktop.org/git/poppler/test

   You should checkout the test data as a sibling of your
   poppler source folder or specify the location of your
   checkout with -DTESTDATADIR=/path/to/checkoutdir/test.

-- Checking for module 'nss>=3.49'
-- No package 'nss' found
-- Could NOT find NSS3 (missing: NSS3_LIBRARIES NSS3_CFLAGS)
CMake Warning at cmake/modules/MacroOptionalFindPackage.cmake:32 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindGpgmepp.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Gpgmepp", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Gpgmepp"
  (requested version 1.19) with any of the following names:

    GpgmeppConfig.cmake
    gpgmepp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Gpgmepp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Gpgmepp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
  "Gpgmepp" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:158 (macro_optional_find_package)

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:198 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core"
  (requested version 5.12) with any of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:199 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Gui.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
    qt5gui-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Gui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Gui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Qt5Gui"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:200 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Xml.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Xml", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Xml" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5XmlConfig.cmake
    qt5xml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Xml" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Xml_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Qt5Xml"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:201 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:202 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Test.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5TestConfig.cmake
    qt5test-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Test" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Test_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
  "Qt5Test" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.

-- Package Qt5Core or Qt5Gui or Qt5Xml or Qt5Widgets or Qt5Test not found
-- Package Qt6Core or Qt6Gui or Qt6Widgets or Qt6Test not found
-- Checking for module 'cairo>=1.16.0'
-- No package 'cairo' found
-- Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.71.0")
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:225 (message):
  -- Boost recommended for Splash. Use ENABLE_BOOST=OFF to skip.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/var/bin/poppler-23.09.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try that :

```
# Update package lists
sudo apt-get update

# Install dependencies
sudo apt-get install libnss3-dev libgpgmepp-dev qtbase5-dev libcairo2-dev libboost-dev
```

The dependencies listed up here are the ones that seems to be missing based on the errors

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the package list to ensure you have the latest information about available packages:
   `sudo apt update`
2. Install the Poppler utilities and libraries using the following command:

`sudo apt install poppler-utils`
This command will install the Poppler utilities, which include pdftotext, pdfinfo, and others, as well as the Poppler libraries.

3. To verify that `Poppler` is installed, you can use the `pdftotext` command as an example:

`pdftotext -v`
This command should display the version of Poppler that was installed.